# Multiple Markers with Data in Text Bubble from Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create a Google Map canvas with markers of indicating two separate Starbucks locations. When I click on each marker, I would like the text bubble to populate with the information Google Maps has regarding the location (address, phone...). I know how to place the marker on the page, but I am having trouble figuring out how to populate the bubble with data from Google Maps.

Comment: What is your specific problem? Do you need help putting content into an InfoBubble? Do you need help retrieving the place information?

Comment: I need help retrieving the place information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by checking out the [**Google Places Library** section of the Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) to get familiar with how it works and then you can use the [**PlacesService** API Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) when you are ready to start coding. All of the related JavaScript classes are also in that area of the API Doc.